# why when I move the head rig the head deforms?

Tags: rigging

I only put 1 bone in the head, from the top of the head to the neck, and I painted the head red in weight paint, but when I test the rig in pose mode, the head got deformed as the rig moves.

Comment: because another bone is probably influencing the head, you could select the whole head mesh and in the dropdown menu on the right of the Vertex Groups list, choose Remove From All Groups, then assign to the head bone again. If it doesn't work, please share the file

Comment: I don't see Remove From All Groups botton. blender 2.81?